# Geometry Pyramidal Cross Section Volume Problem

Tags: geometry

A right square pyramid with base edges of length $8\sqrt{2}$ units each and slant edges of length 10 units each is cut by a plane that is parallel to its base and 3 units above its base. What is the volume, in cubic units, of the new pyramid that is cut off by this plane?

[image]

All I know is the volume for pyramid is Volume = (Area * height)/3. The area of the base is ($8\sqrt{2}$*$8\sqrt{2}$)=32. I then tried to find the height by forming a right triangle with the height being one of the legs and 10 being the hypotenuse, but I am not sure about the angles. Could someone help me please?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Use that $$V_1=k^3V_2$$ since the pyramids are similar.

Answer (score 0):

Use half the diagonal of the base as the third leg.

Since the base is a square with side $8\sqrt{2}$ half the diagonal would be $$\frac12 * \sqrt{2} * 8 \sqrt{2} = 8$$

The right triangle then has legs of length $h$ and $8$ and a hypotenuse of $10$

Can you take it from here?

Also, double check what $8\sqrt{2} * 8 \sqrt{2}$ is equal to; it isn't $32$

Answer (score 0):

It is the matter of finding the length of the base of the new pyramid.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

According to the diagram, △CBD is a right isosceles triangle. Its side is $CB = 8$, given by $2CB^2 = (8\sqrt{2})^2$. Then, the height is $AB=\sqrt{10^2+8^2}=6$.

Therefore, the height of the small pyramid is 3 since the cutoff height is 3. Given the 1:2 height ratio, the base length of the small pyramid is
$8\sqrt{2}/2 = 4\sqrt{2}$.

Then, use the volume formula

$$V = \frac{1}{3} \text{ height} \cdot \text{area} = \frac{1}{3}\times 3 \times (4\sqrt{2})^2 = 32$$